# Adding a jQuery rotator function

Tags: functions, jquery

I wanted to test and use the bellow [function from @kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43045/25187) for a jQuery rotator, but I received an error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? I have followed all instructions of the author.

The function:

```
function add_jquery_rotator()
{
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-rotator', get_stylesheet_directory().'/js/jquery.jshowoff.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), 0, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-rotator' );

    jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
        $( '#quoterotator' ).jshowoff(
        {
             // add your options here - see linked source docu for more details
        } );
    ) };
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jquery_rotator' );
```

The error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting '&' or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /var/www/.../public_html/wp-content/themes/birdtips-child/functions.php
>   on line 293

**# line 293 is the line** `jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {`

Comment: The jQuery part `jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {` should not be in the function. But in `<script>` at footer.php

Comment: you are mixing PHP and JavaScript code

Comment: Not me, this was @kaiser :).